# How do you split a column and create a relation from them?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, grouping, tidyverse

I am a self-learning programmer and I am quite the novice.

I am attempting to create a relationship between groups within a vector.
Below is the code that I am using to accomplish my goal.

There must be a quicker, or general, way to accomplish this goal.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tibble(nums = seq(0,9, by = 1), 
               ltrs = rep(c("a","b"), each = 5))

myspl <- split(mydf, mydf$ltrs)

ltrsA <- myspl[["a"]]$ltrs
ltrsB <- myspl[["b"]]$ltrs

numsA <- myspl[["a"]]$nums
numsB <- myspl[["b"]]$nums

newdf <- tibble(numsA, ltrsA, numsB, ltrsB)
newdf

ggplot(newdf, aes(numsA, numsB)) + geom_point()
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: newdf is basically `do.call('cbind', myspl)` right?

Comment: Your solution works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a task for `bind_cols` from `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf <- tibble(nums = seq(0,9, by = 1), 
               ltrs = rep(c("a","b"), each = 5))

myspl <- split(mydf, mydf$ltrs)

bind_cols(myspl)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
   nums  ltrs nums1 ltrs1
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     0     a     5     b
2     1     a     6     b
3     2     a     7     b
4     3     a     8     b
5     4     a     9     b
```

We can also change the column names after `bind_cols`.

```
myspl %>%
  bind_cols() %>%
  setNames(paste0(names(mydf), rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  numsA ltrsA numsB ltrsB
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     0     a     5     b
2     1     a     6     b
3     2     a     7     b
4     3     a     8     b
5     4     a     9     b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>%
  group_by(ltrs) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(ltrs, nums) %>%
  ggplot(aes(a, b)) + geom_point()
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     ID     a     b
* <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     5
2     2     1     6
3     3     2     7
4     4     3     8
5     5     4     9
```

[image]